# Can I stop geth when it is halfway done and restart it without loosing all the first half of data?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, nodes, datadir

I have started geth (fresh install) using this command:

`geth --datadir "my/path"`

I'm halfway done with sync and would like to restart my PC.

Will I loose all the data accumulated so far or not?

And when I restart the PC, do I have to pass in the `--datadir` argument again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will not lose any data if you restart your computer. The data will live in `my/path`. If you run the same command (with the same `--datadir` path), then the node will continue syncing from where it left off.

With that said, there is a chance that some of the data gets corrupted if you restart your computer without gracefully exiting the sync.